# Turn off built-in rss reader in Firefox 13

Tags: firefox, selenium, rss, automated-tests, molybdenum

A couple of years ago, I designed a bunch of automatic tests for a webapplication using [Molybdenum](https://www.molyb.org/confluence/display/molyb/Home). Some of these checked the data showed in a rss feed through an xml parser. The test required the browser to show the rss as a simple xml file.

At that time I managed to turn off firefox built-in rss reader [changing a parameter in the feedconverter.js file](http://www.walkernews.net/2007/11/20/how-to-view-rss-feed-in-xml-format-with-firefox/). With the major updates in Firefox (4.0 to now) this file is missing and the developers seems to have left no room for this kind of trick.

Do you know a native way to turn off the built-in rss reader?

P.S. = Solutions using the *view-source:* URL suffix does not work in this case, because the *open* command answers **Failure: Access to restricted URI denied**

Comment: If you are checking the XML from the RSS feed why do you need a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Things that **don't** work:

- setting "Web feed" content handler to "Preview in Firefox" (shows formatted HTML version, not plaintext XML)
- setting [`browser.feeds.handler`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.feeds.handler) to "Reader" (this is an `about:config` alternative to above) or anything else. There's no `plaintext` option.
- editing `mimeTypes.rdf` in one's profile folder - Firefox seems not to care about feed settings there
- adding a new web [content handler](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.contentHandlers.types.%2a.uri) with URI `view-source:%s` - I think it was pretty close, but Firefox escapes the forwarded URL and refuses to open it
- [`storeHtmlSource`](https://www.molyb.org/confluence/display/molyb/HtmlSource-accessor-selcore) as it is too smart and does return the code of the formatted page, not the XML source

Comment: I already have the **Web Feed** value set to **Preview in Firefox**, Firefox 13 still shows me the formatted html version of the feed.

Comment: Oh. I kinda thought you wanted that one, sorry. I made a community wiki from my answer to show my nonworking ideas, someone could possibly make them work

Comment: What does [storeHtmlSource](https://www.molyb.org/confluence/display/molyb/HtmlSource-accessor-selcore) command return? It should give you the original static source file... Also, another idea is to create a simple program that would save the file locally as txt, set Firefox to use that program for feeds, and then open `file:///C://myFile.txt` in Molybdenum.

Comment: The command  `storeHtmlSource ` returns the formatted HTML code. Thank you for your support.

Comment: The idea above could work, but besides that, I'm drained now.